# difference between <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /> ,<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" />

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT, when I saw few existing xslt files in my project I saw the following snippets,

1. `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />`
2. `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" />`

Could someone please explain what is difference between the above 2?
Thanks, Kitty

Answer (score 3):

`node()` matches elements, text nodes, processing instructions and comments. So `node()` is the same as doing `*|text()|processing-instruction()|comment()`

`*` just matches elements

`@*` matches attributes

So, if you had the following XML

```
<Root Attribute="1">
  Text Node
  <Element>Text</Element>
</Root>
```

Then, assuming you were positioned on the `Root` node, if you did `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />` then it would select `Attribute`, `Text Node` and `Element`. But `<xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*" />` would select only `Attribute` and `Element`.